# First item in RecyclerView not clickable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am currently implementing the ability to click on an item of an `RecyclerView` in an Android App. Yet I am stuck with some weird bug where I can only register the clicks on all items but the first one.

This is my layout for each item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="listItemClick">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="     "
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spacer2"
        android:text="[Auftraggeber] - [Ort]"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/captionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerTextView"
        android:text="Erstellt am 21.05.1999" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/captionTextView"
        android:text="     "
        android:textSize="8sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using the `listItemClick` in my `MainActivity` in order to execute code upon clicking on an item. Further more i'm passing data through the tag of one of the textviews (which I assume not to be the problem).

This is `listItemClick()`:

```
public void listItemClick (View v){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("You clicked: " + v.findViewById(R.id.headerTextView).getTag()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }
```

This is the Adapter I implemented for the RecyclerView:

```
public class RapportListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RapportListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<RapportStructure> mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
        public ViewHolder(RelativeLayout v) {
            super(v);
            mRelativeLayout = v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("WORKS");
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public RapportListAdapter(ArrayList<RapportStructure> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public RapportListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.celllayout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(rl);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        TextView headerTextView = (TextView) holder.mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);
        TextView captionTextView = (TextView) holder.mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.captionTextView);

        RapportStructure rs = this.mDataset.get(position);

        headerTextView.setText("ClientID:" + rs.getClientId() + " - " + rs.getPlace());
        captionTextView.setText("Erstellt am " + rs.getCreatedOn().toString());

        headerTextView.setTag(position);
    }



    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }


}
```

I would like the first list item to be clickable as well. If you need any more information, just ask :)

Comment: Could you share us your adapter?

Comment: How did you implement clicking on `RecyclerView` item? Can you share your `adapter` code?

Comment: How do you use listItemClick() method? Do you have any Adapter for the list?

Comment: Added the Adapter Code

Comment: Somehow, I don't know why, it seems to work now. I didn't change anything. Thanks for all the help though!

Answer (score 1):

I too have current problem.
after remove animation, my problem resolved. ):

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to have killed itself. I don't know why. I can use the first element now to open up a new `Activity`. Thanks for all the help!